# Integrating MS Office with PHP & SQLServer Filetables

Tags: php, sql-server, filetable

I have implemented a Document Management System (Web Application) in PHP which stores all documents on SQL server in Filetable. The Software works fine with Downloading the document, modifying it and uploading back to the server.

My Question :

1: When the file is downloaded the browser handles it as an attachment and could be opened in MS-Word by the user. Is it possible to open the document in particular application for e.g in MS-Word? Make changes to the document and while saving the document it saves/uploads directly to the SQL server. So that the user doesn't have to upload it back from my web application.

I would appreciate any leads to the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup webdav endpoints which interacts with your file database.
See also this question:
[Open remote document and save back to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884139/open-remote-document-and-save-back-to-remote-server)

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in SQL with name **FileTables** this allow for client application (ex: ms word) to open the file directly from Database using network share folder. This also allow to store directly to database without any programming.

I also come up with this question and see this as an options. But I still didn't know if this feature can be combined with WebDAV.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/compare-options-for-storing-blobs-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15